# Keep a circuit closed after activating a reed switch NO (normally open)

Tags: transistors, switches, inductor, reed-switch, circuits

I need a circuit that it is open until I bring near a magnet that closes a NO reed switch for a short interval of time. I need the circuit keep closed for ever.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a double-pole, single or double-throw relay. This will have two sets of contacts. You use one of them to control the relay, and the other to provide your circuit closure.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxqFD5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What operating current will you accept? A CMOS flip-flop, with SET pin driven from the reed-relay, the Q output driving a big MOSFET switch, will have "zero" standbye current.

Answer (score 1):

A latching / bi-stable relay should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You mean forever till you remove power? Or some other method .

The reed can be activated by a magnet or coil current (electromagnet) with the correct polarities in both cases.

Thus the magnet induced closed contacts can connect  the coil to rated DC to keep closed until DC is removed.

This is the simplest latch.